# google map triggering event not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented google map event trigger. However it seems no events are triggered/called. So I add function initialize above the code, because the glob var is located in another file. However, new problem occurs, the tabs are gone.

Couple of questions: 1) Is global var added correctly? 2) Do I have to add google.maps.event into the tabs constructor? 3) I tried a lot, but map seems to be still broken. Any solutions for this?

```
 ?>        
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $geo_latitude;?>, <?php echo $geo_longitude;?>);
        Demo.map = new google.maps.Map(Demo.mapContainer, {
            <?php 
            if(get_option('ptthemes_scale_factor')){ 
                $ptthemes_scale_factor = get_option('ptthemes_scale_factor');
            } else {
                $ptthemes_scale_factor = 13;
            }
            ?>
            zoom: <?php echo $ptthemes_scale_factor;?>,
            center: latLng,
            <?php 
            if($map_type=='Road Map' || $map_type=='Satellite Map'|| $map_type=='Terrain Map'){
                if($map_type=='Satellite Map') { 
                    $map_type = SATELLITE; 
                } elseif($map_type=='Terrain Map') { 
                    $map_type = TERRAIN; 
                } else { 
                    $map_type = ROADMAP; 
                } 
                ?>
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.<?php echo $map_type;?>
            <?php 
            } else {
            ?>
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            <?php 
            }
            ?>
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng, 
            map: Demo.map,
            title:"<?php echo trim($post->post_title);?>"
        });     

        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                activate: function(e, ui) {                                
                    google.maps.event.trigger(Demo.map, "resize");
                }
            });
        });
    }
    </script>
```

The global var is defined here:

```
init: function() {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $geo_latitude;?>, <?php echo $geo_longitude;?>);
    Demo.map = new google.maps.Map(Demo.mapContainer, {
        <?php 
        if(get_option('ptthemes_scale_factor')) { 
            $ptthemes_scale_factor = get_option('ptthemes_scale_factor');}
        else {
             $ptthemes_scale_factor = 13;
        }
        ?>
        zoom: <?php echo $ptthemes_scale_factor;?>,
        center: latLng,
        <?php 
        if($map_type=='Road Map' || $map_type=='Satellite Map'|| $map_type=='Terrain Map'){
            if($map_type=='Satellite Map') { 
                $map_type = SATELLITE; 
            } elseif($map_type=='Terrain Map') { 
                 $map_type = TERRAIN; 
            } else { 
                $map_type = ROADMAP; 
            } ?>
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.<?php echo $map_type;?>
            <?php 
        } else {
        ?>
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng, 
        map: Demo.map,
        title:"<?php echo trim($post->post_title);?>"
    });   
}
```

Comment: try to fix your coding -errors first please, there exist a lot of fine tools to localize parse-errors(SO  isn't such a tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a JavaScript parse error. There is an extra closing brace `}` on line 484. Fix that and see if your problem still occurs.

Comment: thanks for help. I've just removed the }, however  there is an unexpected end of input on line 488. Any clue what to do next??

Comment: fix the code, but do you know why the tabs are gone??

Comment: Your `initialize()` function is never called. Since you are using jQuery, instead of calling an initialize function, just wrap the code in a `jQuery(document).ready()` call.

Comment: Thanks! finally the function is called!